# Call mysql through odbc and excel

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc

I am calling a query through an odbc connection from excel.

I have a where clause where I want to use dates.

This works for a date
sale.saledate>={d '2012-10-29'}

But I need to add time in also

I tried
sale.saledate>={d '2012-10-29 3:30 PM'}

But this does not work.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try {ts '2012-10-29 15:30:00'}. Search for ODBC date time formats. ODBC has its own syntax for dates, times and timestamps which the driver is supposed to translate to the database.

Comment: I did not know that ODBC has it's own date time formats.  Thanks